# Some basic question on pasting map from a square to a Klein bottle and homology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider a square $S$ which edges identified as follows

[image]

Let $K$ be a Klein bottle and $p:S\to K$ be pasting map. Let $X$ be the image of the interior of $S$ under $p$ and let $Y$ be the image of a neighborhood of $\delta S$. I know that $X$ is homeomorphic to an open disk, but it was written that $X\cap Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$? I think it is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\vee S^1$ because the boundary is. What is the generator of $H_1(X\cap Y)=\mathbb{Z}$ then if it is homotopic to $S^1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the restriction of $p$ to $S\setminus\delta S$ is a homeomorphism onto $X$.  So $X\cap Y$, being a subset of $X$, is homeomorphic to a subset of the open unit square.  Which subset is that?  Well, $p^{-1}(Y)$ is just a small neighborhood of $\delta S$, so $Y\cap X$ will look like a small open ring along the edge of the square, but not actually containing the boundary.  This open ring is homeomorphic to an annulus, and hence homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.  A generator of $H_1(X\cap Y)$ is a loop which goes around just inside the boundary of $S$.

The key point here is that $X\cap Y$ doesn't actually contain any of $\delta S$, so the fact that the boundary edges of $S$ are identified does not affect the topology of $X\cap Y$.

Comment: The klein bottle stuff is irrelevant here right ? The same hold for the torus.

Comment: @EricWofsey, Oh I see. OK I got it now. $X\cap Y$ doesn't actually contain any of $\delta S$. I was mistaken before. OK thanks so much :)